# Xen server change from eth0 to eth1

Tags: vps, xen

I have a Xen server (solusvm slave) and the eth0 is broken. I switched it to eth1.  The main IP now works, but the VPS IPs no longer work.  How do I get them to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your bridge settings to enslave eth1 instead of eth0 ?

Comment: Fixed it by modifying: /usr/local/solusvm/data/advanced.conf
Here's the guide:
http://wiki.solusvm.com/index.php/Advanced_Configuration